# Real Analysis. Convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am asked to Show that the sequence $\{1/n\}$ converges to $0$. I used the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition . The proof goes as follows:
Let $\epsilon >0$ .
For $1/\epsilon \in \mathbb R$, by Archimedian property there is a natural number $N$ such that
$N> 1/\epsilon$.
Consider, $n\ge N$
implies $n> 1/\epsilon$
imples $1/n < \epsilon$
implies $|1/n - 0|< \epsilon$

So, the limiting value of $1/n$ as $n$ tends to infinity is $0$.

My question is can i take any other real number $2/\epsilon$ or $3/\epsilon$ instead of $1/\epsilon$ in the step using Archimedian property? kindly want to know that "for every $\epsilon > 0$" in the definition means the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, yes, as you can easily verify that if $N>2/\epsilon$ for example, then $n\ge N$ implies $|1/n - 0|< \epsilon/2<\epsilon$.

For the second question, I guess you are asking what "for every $\epsilon>0$ means. It means that for every $\epsilon>0$, we can find such an $N$ satisfying that property. So, from the proof above, we know, for example, if $\epsilon=0.001$, then $N=1000000$ is OK. The proof is valid for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thank you. I got more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|a_n-A|$ means the absolute error between $a_n$ and $A$, $\epsilon$ can be taken as a "challenge".

If for any given "challenge" $\epsilon$, there always exists a "response" $N$ such that when $n>N$, the absolute error will be small than the "challenge" value $\epsilon$, then you can know that the error can be arbitrary small and so we can say it "finally" goes to 0, hence $A$ is the required limit value. This is all that the definition said.

Yes, You also can prove $|a_n-A|<k\epsilon$ ($k \in \mathbb{R}_+$) instead, for the reason below:

**Proof:**
If for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$, $|a_n-A|<k\epsilon$, then since $\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{k}>0$, there is $N' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N'$, $|a_n-A|<k\epsilon'=\epsilon$.

But if you can use the original definition, I don't think it's necessary to prove by this way - since it may get people unfamiliar with.